# Analog Audio Tape Equalization: Why a Time Constant instead of a Corner Frequency?

Tags: audio, filter

For recording or playing back audio signals with analog tape, frequencies on the low and high ends of the audio spectrum are run through filters (equalized). The filters are [standardized](http://www.iasa-web.org/tc04/magnetic-tapes-replay-equalisation). The goal is to obtain a flat frequency response with a system that has a number of nonlinearities and non-ideal properties (high frequency noise, ...) as detailed in [this document](http://www.ant-audio.co.uk/Tape_Recording/Library/EQ.pdf).

In a nutshell, while playing back, and depending on the standard used, low frequencies are sometimes boosted, and high frequencies are always cut.

Opposed to most other filters used in electronics, the filters used for tape equalization are not characterized using corner frequencies, but time constants (e.g. 3180 µs and 70 µs for CrO<sub>2</sub> or Type II tape, corresponding to 50 Hz and 2.27 kHz, respectively). What's the reason for using time constants instead of corner frequencies?

Comment: RC time constant for legacy filter designs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, time constant and corner frequency are directly related: F<sub>C</sub> = 1/(2πτ). It's really just a matter of historical convention. When equalization was first invented (for disk recording and FM broadcast, for example), the engineers who came up with those standards preferred to think in terms of time constants. It became the convention that later standards (for tape recording, etc.) also followed.

Answer (score 4):

Time constant and corner frequency are simply related, as Dave Tweed says. Either will unambiguously define the circuit requirements.

But it's not just a matter of historical convention; time constant is easier to use for a circuit designer. Pick a suitable C, find R such that RC = time constant.

These things mattered in the days before Matlab, Spice, spreadsheets and pocket calculators!

Comment: As long as your slide rule has a 1/x scale, and pi and 2pi markings, doing the conversion isn't all *that* difficult :-) :-)

Comment: True! I never had a proper 12" slide rule, though.